# Textarea open a pop-up when click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use a textarea to encourage people to comment, but before they comment they need to login or register first. I have this login/register form open using modal pop-up, by clicking url "#" with class "popup-login".

How can I make the textarea open that modal pop-up login window when clicked (using jQuery)? Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use `$('#yourId').focus(function() {openPopup()});`

Comment: I need a jQuery function to simulate click for this url: <a href="#" class="popup-login">login</a> . Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the click event for the `.popup-login` set up, this code should work fine.

```
// We are using focus instead of click to prevent the user from tabbing onto the comment box
$('#comment').on('focus', function() {
  $('.popup-login').click();
  // This will remove focus from the comment box
  $(this).blur();
});
```

Here's a full example

```js
$('#comment').on('focus', function() {
  $('.popup-login').click();
  $(this).blur();
});

$('.popup-login').on('click', function() {
  alert('This is where the popup would be');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="popup-login">Login</a>
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
```

Comment: It works like a charm.. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.. :-)

Comment: No problem! Consider marking this answer as correct to help other people find it in the future

Answer (score 1):

Create a `function` that opens the modal. Then, call the function with `onClick`:

```js
function modal() {
  document.getElementById('textarea').value="This would open a modal window";
}
```

```css
textarea {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">
  <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Write a comment..."disabled></textarea>
  <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;" onClick="modal()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What value needs to open the modal popup link? The modal url is: <a href="#" class="popup-login">login</a>

Comment: So assuming you have some jQuery that opens your modal onClick, etc:
`$('#popup-login').on('click', function() {
  //opens modal
});`, then simply take the `//open modal` part and put it inside the function.

Comment: I get your idea.. You save my day, thanks for your help :-)

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, could you accept my answer?